Why is a crossing of 2 arcs defined like this here?
The below text defines a crossing for 2 arcs, where $a_ib_j$ is a Jordan arc of finite length terminating at 2 distinct points $a_i$ and $b_j$:

Two arcs $a_i b_j, a_k b_l(i \neq k, j \neq l)$ are said to have a crossing if $a_i b_j$ can be closed by a curve connecting $a_i$ to $b_j$ which is disjoint from $a_k b_l$ and such that there are points of $a_k b_l$ both inside and outside the closed curve.

I am confused how this is possible- I looked up what a closed curve is, and I imagine to close an arc with a curve like this means that a closed curve "encircles" or "envelops" the arc. However, it doesn't seem possible for points of $a_kb_l$ to lie both inside and outside this closed curve when this closed curve is disjoint from $a_kb_l$, as both the closed curve and $a_kb_l$ are continuous.Why couldn't we simply have said that $a_ib_j$ and $a_kb_l$ share a common point which isn't there endpoints?
For context, I am learning about Zarankiewizc's conjecture, and the crossing is defined for a way of modelling the crossing of 2 edges of a bipartite graph. For context, the full passage is here:

Let $K_{m, n}$ denote the complete bipartite graph on sets of $m$ and $n$ vertices, that is, the graph whose edges join exactly those pairs of vertices which belong one to each set. Let $D_{m, n}$ denote a drawing of $K_{m, n}$, that is, a mapping of $K_{m, n}$ into the plane which takes the vertices into distinct points $a_i, b_j(1 \leqslant i \leqslant n, 1 \leqslant j \leqslant m)$, called nodes, and the edges into Jordan arcs of finite length terminating at the appropriate nodes. A drawing is said to be good if no two arcs have more than one point in common, and such a common point is either a node which is a terminal point for each of the arcs or is a crossing. Two arcs $a_i b_j, a_k b_l(i \neq k, j \neq l)$ are said to have a crossing if $a_i b_j$ can be closed by a curve connecting $a_i$ to $b_j$ which is disjoint from $a_k b_l$ and such that there are points of $a_k b_l$ both inside and outside the closed curve.


Closing the curve means extending it to a closed curve.

@CheerfulParsnip If extending a curve here means to create a new closed curve that includes the original curve as part of it, how could we be disjoint from $a_kb_l$ if we cross it with the curve we are extending? Do they mean only the new part of the extended curve is disjoint?

@CheerfulParsnip Also I still don't see why we don't just define a crossing by saying we can't have a common point which isn't the endpoints

There is a difference between an arc crossing another one transversely or not. If they intersect at a common tangent, you wouldn't want to say they cross.

Regarding why it makes sense for the points of $a_kb_l$ to lie both inside and outside the closed curve (where the closed curve is produced, as @CheerfulParsnip noted, by extending the original curve), the curve encloses either $a_k$ or $b_l$, such that we no longer have to worry about passing through the extended portion of this curve by the arc $a_kb_l$. Regarding why there wasn't the simpler definition, perhaps the author intends to use arguments crucially using the fact that there exists another such a curve later on, although this remains to be seen.
I welcome further answers to this post regarding the motivation behind choosing this definition.
